# JNI C++ templates to acquire/release resources

Tags: c++, templates, java-native-interface, release

What is recommended template set or library to acquire/release JNI resources from C++ code?

"Bad" example:

```
//C++ code
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring javaString)
{
    //Get the native string from javaString
    const char *nativeString = env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString, 0);

    //Do something with the nativeString

    //DON'T FORGET THIS LINE!!!
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString, nativeString);
}
```

Obviously, everybody uses a template set, not the code above.

For jstring it calls GetStringUTFChars to acquire resource and ReleaseStringUTFChars to release, when object goes "out of scope".

Gotta be something similar to auto_ptr template, but tailored to JNI to call GetStringUTFChars/ReleaseStringUTFChars for jstring, for example.

Comment: It's not template, but [Jace](http://code.google.com/p/jace/) seems well established for this kind of need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keyword here is [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization):

```
class jni_string {
public:
    jni_string(JNIEnv *env, jstring javaString)
        : env_(env), javaString_(javaString)
    { nativeString_ = env_->GetStringUTFChars(javaString_, 0); }

    ~jni_string() { env_->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString_, nativeString_); }

    operator const char *() const { return nativeString_; }
private:
    jni_string(const jni_string &x);
    jni_string &operator=(const jni_string &x);

    JNIEnv *env_;
    jstring javaString_;
    const char *nativeString_;
};
```

Usage would be:

```
//C++ code
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring javaString)
{
    //Get the native string from javaString
    jni_string nativeString(env, javaString);

    //Do something with the nativeString
}
```

Comment: You should either handle copying/assignment or disable them to prevent accidental errors.

Comment: @DaveS Thanks for spotting, fixed.

Comment: >The keyword here is RAII:
It is. I didn't put it into question, so I don't have to explain what it is. ;-)

I'm sure there is a set of JNI related templates 99.999% coders use.

Since it is well know stuff, there no way to Google it out. :-(

I definitely don’t want reinvent the wheel.

Even less make a (subtle) mistake and spend hours figuring out what’s wrong.

So back to original question, what is that JNI template set, I cannot find?

Comment: Ok, then I haven't really answered your question. But Google www.google.de/search?q=jni+template+library has two hits: [JNITL](https://github.com/kohsuke/jnitl) and [JTL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtl/).

Comment: Olaf,
Wow!
Looks like, that’s exactly what I was after.
Let me try 1st one and I’ll be right back.
BTW: Another proof, my Googling suck... :-(

Comment: Ok. I didn’t say from very beginning, I’m looking for JNI template library for Android (NDK).
JNITL is for windows and need a bit of overhaul.
JTL is boost based... Don’t want to bring whole boost lib to small application.
*But they both JNI template libraries indeed.*
There is one more mentioned in "JNI - C++ integration made easy - Technion" article - I can compile it with MS VS, but no luck with NDK (no enough macro length?)
Since it’s entirely my fault, I’m marking Olaf reply as answer and giving thumbs up to another reply.
I you see "JNI template library for NDK' in a wild, let me know!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) in C++11, which allows you to set the deleter yourself:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

typedef std::unique_ptr<char const[], std::function<void(char const*)>> jni_string_ptr;
// the "std::function" is needed to store any callable†

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring javaString)
{
    //Get the native string from javaString
    jni_string_ptr nativeString(env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString, 0),
        [=](char const* p) mutable{ env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(javaString, p); });
    // lambda as the deleter
    // mutable needed if "ReleaseStringUTFChars" is a non-const method

    //Do something with the nativeString

    // nativeString automatically calls the passed deleter
}
```

If you're stuck in C++03 and don't have access to `std::unique_ptr`, [`boost::shared_array`](http://www.boost.org/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) provides a.. *viable* alternative.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

typedef boost::shared_array<char const*> jni_string_ptr;

struct jni_string_deleter{
  jni_string_deleter(JNIEnv* e, jstring js)
    : _env(e), _java_string(js) {}

  void operator()(char const* p) const{
    _env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(_java_string, p);
  }

private:
  JNIEnv* _env;
  jstring _java_string;
};

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ClassName_MethodName
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jstring javaString)
{
    //Get the native string from javaString
    jni_string_ptr nativeString(env->GetStringUTFChars(javaString, 0),
        jni_string_deleter(env, javaString));

    //Do something with the nativeString

    // nativeString automatically calls the passed deleter
}
```

---

† You can also use a specific delter type here, as with the `shared_array` example, to avoid the type-erasure overhead of `std::function`:

```
struct jni_string_deleter{
  jni_string_deleter(JNIEnv* e, jstring js)
    : _env(e), _java_string(js) {}

  void operator()(char const* p) const{
    _env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(_java_string, p);
  }

private:
  JNIEnv* _env;
  jstring _java_string;
};

typedef std::unique_ptr<char const[], jni_string_deleter> jni_string_ptr;

// create
jni_string_ptr(env->get_the_chars(), jni_string_deleter(env, javaString));
```

Comment: One minor suggestion would be to use `std::unique_ptr<const char[], ...>` if you want to be able to use `operator[]` vs. `operator*`.  For a similar case for C++03, you could use `boost::shared_array`.

Comment: Oh, and `make_shared` isn't used correctly here.  `make_shared` creates a new object of the relevant type (in this case a single `const char`), and passes the arguments along to perform construction.  It doesn't support custom deletion either. In this case, I recommend just using then normal `shared_ptr` constructors.

Comment: @Dave: Of course you're right, don't ask me how I messed that up... Edited and fixed both problems.

Comment: Guys,
Thank a lot for the input!

Still wondering, is there **well known JNI template set** somewhere?

Or everybody writes his own set?

Comment: What about error conditions (GetStringUTFChars() returning NULL)? Is this a problem when using the unique_ptr approach?